# Why do we need redirect after sending post request?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

There are 3 forms for update data on the page: 1st is for user profile, 2nd - for password reset, 3rd - for changing e-mail. I made sending forms to controller and redirect to the same page. Project team leader asked to remove those redirects and said that people don't refresh the page after submitting the form and redirects will only load the server...
I could be wrong but redirects are always supposed to be done after sending POST request. My suggestion about making all forms via AJAX was declined. How can I prove competently that there is a need for redirect if I'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point you are looking for is the *Post-Redirect-Get* pattern.
You can read the original article here: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post

It exposes all the motives ; in short, the pattern prevent double-submit (because the page is slow, so the user loose patience) and allows the browser to safely refresh the (last) page, without risking to re-submit data (or at least having that pop-up warning you you are re-submitting data).

Answer (score 2):

Redirect after Submitting form is needed, You should be doing this now I assume:

1. You submit the form
2. Save details in DB
3. Returns the view from the controller.

There would be a problem in above case, When the form is submitted and you return the plain view to the user without redirecting the page and on the view user **tries to refresh** the page he will get the following warning message.

> The page that you're looking for used information that you entered.
>   Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated.
>   Do you want to continue.

This means browser will again send those data which has been processed in  previous request, due to this there might be some ambiguity in data processed on server side.

This could be a reason to redirect the page just after submitting and processing the form.

Answer (score 2):

The redirect is only for clearing all post data. If you choose not to redirect, the user can experience some inconvenience when he uses the back or forward buttons. He will be asked to send the post data again.